# Bootstrap side navbar doesn't work when I have includes (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

My code works just fine if it is in html file, the header and footer codes are in the products page. The problem is if I make it in php file, the side navbar won't work, I already tried moving the body tag in the products page but it still doesn't work. Appreciate any help :)

**header-ee.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        include('parameters.php');
    ?>
    <title> <?php echo $page_title; ?> </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= $server_addr ?>/common/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="<?= $server_addr ?>/common/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="<?= $server_addr ?>/common/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ee-home.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ee-home.css">
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">
    <!--Start header-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navigation-bar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="navbar-header col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 centered-a">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 centered-a">
                            <img src="img/ee-logo.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <h1 id="nav-brand">
                                EQUIPMENT ENGINEERS, INC.</br>
                            </h1>   
                            <h1 id="nav-brand-subtitle">
                                <small>
                                    Your Reliable Solutions Partner
                                </small>
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="link-spanner"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-header col-lg-6 visible-lg centered-a">
                    <div class="row centered-a" id="nav-box">
                        <div class="col-lg-2 centered-a">
                            <a href="#">
                                <p>Home</p>
                                <span class="link-spanner"></span>
                            <a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 centered-a">
                            <a href="#">
                                <p>Our Company</p>
                                <span class="link-spanner"></span>
                            <a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 centered-a">
                            <a href="#">
                                <p>SCM</p>
                                <span class="link-spanner"></span>
                            <a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 centered-a">
                            <a href="#">
                                <p>Products</p>
                                <span class="link-spanner"></span>
                            <a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 centered-a">
                            <a href="#">
                                <p>Inquiries</p>
                                <span class="link-spanner"></span>
                            <a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 centered-a" id="last-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <p">Supplier Accreditation</p>
                                <span class="link-spanner"></span>
                            <a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-group col-md-12 centered-a hidden-lg">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" >
                        <h2 class="panel-title centered-a">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">
                                <span class="link-spanner"></span>
                            <a>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                Home
                                <a href="#"><span class="link-spanner"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                Our Company
                                <a href="#"><span class="link-spanner"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                SCM
                                <a href="#"><span class="link-spanner"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                Products
                                <a href="#"><span class="link-spanner"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                Inquiries
                                <a href="#"><span class="link-spanner"></span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                Supplier Accreditation
                                <a href="#"><span class="link-spanner"></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--End header-->
```

**products.php**

```
<?php include("includes/header-ee.php"); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="products.css"></link>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Sidebar-->
        <nav class="col-md-3" id="myScrollspy">
            <span>Product Lineup</span>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div id="section1">   
                <div class="bg-franklin bg-img centered-a">
                    <div class="caption" style="border:10px; border-color:white;">
                        <img src="img/products/franklin.png" style="width:50%; background-color:white;"></img>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; font-size: 1.2em; text-align:left;padding: 0% 3%;">
                    </br>

                    </br></br>

                    </br></br>


                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="section2">   
                <div class="bg-franklin bg-img centered-a">
                    <div class="caption" style="border:10px; border-color:white;">
                        <img src="img/products/franklin.png" style="width:50%; background-color:white;"></img>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; font-size: 1.2em; text-align:left;padding: 0% 3%;">
                    </br>

                    </br></br>

                    </br></br>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include("includes/footer-ee.php"); ?>
```

**footer-ee.php**

```
</body>

<footer>
    <div class="footer-blk row">
        <div style="float: none;text-align: center;">
            Home | Terms and Conditions | Privacy Policy 
        </div>
        <div style="float: none;text-align: center;">

        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: what are the notices or warnings that you are getting?

Comment: Well I haven't spent alot of time looking at this code and I can already spot that you have your footer tag outside of the body of the page, which will never render. This is probably another issue entirely, but I might suggest going over your imports, you're also not even ending the initial HTML element.

Comment: Also that stylesheet link should be in the head, not in products.

Comment: Do you speak spanish?,

Comment: I added the ending tag for body and html under the footer, its still the same though, I also put the stylesheet link in the head, still the same though. The nav bar works just that, whenever you scroll, the section you are in should be highlighted (in the nav bar), however in my case it stays and only highlights section 2. However when you click a section, it will redirect you to that section. As for the notices or warnings, I don't see any, probably because I'm using notepad++.

Comment: No, I don't speak spanish.